# Android Parse Push notication showing can't find any register device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new for parse.com and trying push notification. so i refer this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

i changed the application ID and client key also. i am using push notification as a test purpose. but Parse.com showing "Can't find any registered devices yet..." though i installed it in device.

[image: img]

I did  same as the tutorial.

My Manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.samplepushnotificationparse">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.samplepushnotificationparse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.samplepushnotificationparse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".CustomPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.samplepushnotificationparse" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: have you debug your application? are you able to receive the deviceId